# 2D fft - Null imaginary part

Tags: python, c++, image, algorithm, fft

I am integrating a Python routine into C++ code.

There is the computation of the fft 2D of some real matrix, using in Python

```
F_BLK=np.fft.fft2(blk)
```

`F_BLK` is a complex 512*24 matrix, with coefficients complex with real and imag part with order of magnitude 10e5.

When I compute the fft2 of the matrix in C++ i get a complex matrix with complex coefficients **with real part with order of magnitude 10e6 and with null imaginary part**.

- ***What does it mean if the fft2 has got null imaginary part*** ?
- What are possible sources for such wrong results ?
- Would you recommend one library in C++ for computing fft2 ?

Comment: I added answer but without more info about yours FFT data and implementations it is all just educated guess ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you use real input for FFT

   - then you do not need to have so much calculations ( C += R * C is simpler then C += C * C)
   - so if you have FFT C = f(R) coded for such input data then it is usually faster
   - then standard FFT C= f(C)
   - and also you do not need to have allocated memory for the input imaginary part
   - also when input data is real only then the FFT output is symmetric
   - so you can just compute only first half of output data and mirror the rest
2. the magnitude difference

   - either you have wrong implementation of FFT (in python or in C++)
   - or you just have different normalization coefficients
   - plot the data and compare if the difference is just constant scale factor
   - if not then you have bug in FFT implementation somewhere or the python FFT is not FFT
   - also do not forget that data size for any FFT must be power of 2
   - if your implementation expects that then also that could be the cause of error
   - so try resize matrix 512x24 to 512x32 by zero padding before FFT
   - another thing that can cause this can be overflow errors
   - if you mix huge and small numbers together your accuracy get lost
   - especially by FFT recursions the output magnitude can be 10e5 but the subresults can be much much bigger !!!
3. 2D FFT

   - look here [2D FFT,DCT by 1D FFT,DCT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779268/2521214)
   - it contains slow 1D DFT,iDFT implementations in C++ (`R->C`,`C->R`)
   - and algorithm how to compute 2D transforms with it
   - with correct results so you can check yours