# How to do a Fourier Transform of an image using haskell

Tags: haskell, image-processing, fft, fftw, repa

How does one do the Discrete Fourier Transformation of an image using haskell. I believe the two libraries [repa-devil](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-devil-0.3.2.2) and [repa-fftw](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-fftw-3.2.3.2) could be helpful, but I do not know how to integrate them. The reason why I would like this is so I could experiment with hybrid images (I have the wonderful idea that instead of filtering the images separately and then averaging them, I could simply do a weighted average based on frequency.)

Note: Also once one has done this, how would one reinterpret it as an image.

Note: I am not actually sure how one exactly applies dft the image processing. I have seen the equations and know how one would evaluate them, and know the "meaning" for 1D and a rough idea for 2D. I also know how one can some how use it to filter out high or low "frequencies" of an image somehow. I just am not sure exactly how complex frequency images are generated using dft.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? At what point could you not combine your Repa `Array`s from repa-devil with repa-fftw's `fft2d`?

Comment: If you have a greyscale image (`Array F DIM2 Word8`), convert the Word8 to Complex and use `fft2d` directly - this much should be obvious. If you have a colour image, the usual procedure is to perform the FFT on each colour channel individually. You need to convert `Array F DIM3 Word8` to `Array F DIM2 Word8`, to do this, take a look at `Data.Array.Repa.Slice`, namely the `slice` function.

Comment: @user2407038 So they are just interpreted as complex numbers with imaginary part 0? Like `(:+ 0) . fromIntegral :: Word8 -> Complex Float`?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your 2D image (matrix) also by 1D transforms

1. first convert your image to matrix

   - FFT need complex domain
   - so for BW image set imaginary part as 0 and real part to pixel intensity
   - if you have color image then proces each color band as separate image
2. apply 2D transform (DFT,DCT,...)

   - here is an example [2D DCT by 1D DFT transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779268/2521214) in C++
   - at the bottom of that answer are the details for this
   - you just convert all rows of matrix
   - and then all columns
   - +/- some normalization constant scaling
3. now do your stuff on frequency domain
4. convert back to time domain

   - almost the same as bullet 2.
   - just use inverse transforms and inverse normalization scaling constant
5. convert matrix back to image

[Notes]

- FFT has complex output
- so you need extract color from it for example as `intensity = sqrt (re*re+im*im);`
- I use DCT for spectral analysis it is more intuitive