# have an intuition for IDCT, need intuition for DCT

Tags: algorithm, compression, jpeg, dct

I have a good intuition on how does the 2-D IDCT that underlies the JPEG decoder works, especially after seeing the animation at the bottom of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform.

I also understand that it can be formulated simply as: 
[image: idct]

However, I'm not sure I understand the intuition behind the forward DCT. It's also expressed as:
[image: dct]

But for some reason `s(x,y,u,v) = r(x,y,u,v)`. Why is it?

Also, the intuition I have for `s` is: every T(u,v) is little 8X8 image, where T(0,0) is smooth, and t(8,8) is a checkerboard. The value of a pixel `F(3,7)` is a linear combination of each of the value of `(3,7)` in each one of those images. `s(3,7,u,v)` represents this value in each image.

So for example, I can assume that `s(3,7,u,v)` is positive for the little images in which `(3,7)` is closer to white (255), and negative for those in which it is dark (0).

Is this a good intuition? Can you supply a similar, non-math intuition for `r`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I dont get the `intuition` did you mean `understanding` instead? DCT converts continuous signal from time to frequency domain in images the time is x or y axis coordinate. IDCT is the reverse conversion. From FFT analogy you can describe `r` and `s` as kernels which are very similar to each other. but to get behind IDCT physical/geometrical kernel basis meaning is not a good idea. If you want just to compute then use FFT for that it is way much faster then FDCT/iFDCT and more documented see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22779268/2521214

Comment: sorry guys, guess I wasn't clear enough :( I'll try once more in math-overflow, and close this question.