# Feature extraction using discrete cosine transform (DCT)?

Tags: algorithm, fft, dct

[This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-the-difference-between-a-fourier-transform-and-a-cosine-transform) question in this community discuss why in speech recognition, the front end generally does signal processing to allow feature extraction from the audio stream. It is nicely explained there,why to prefer DCT over DFT in the second step. But as this process is hardware based implies that there will be some standard circuits for DFT/DCT transform.

when I googled up for FFT algorithm I found some nice material [here](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/course/451/l/pdf/c6.pdf). But in my current project I need to use DCT. Can someone please point to any standard DCT algorithm/chip which can be used for feature extraction for speech signal?

Comment: This is a dup of a question asked in the more appropriate dsp stackexchange site.

Comment: fast **DCT** is tricky because it has 3 terms subdivision from which one is **DST**. also the literature is vague on this (never saw functional equation for this anywhere all I saw was not working properly) I solve **FDCT** by computing it from **FDFT** (equations for that are OK in most papers) see  [how to compute DCT by DFT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22779268/2521214)