# DCT with low complexity

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, dct

I successfully computed 2d dct of an image using the classic algorithm and also using as a combination of 1d arrays. Those 2 methods have a time complexity of n^4 and n^3 respectively.
While implementing on an image it takes a very long time to compute. like 7 minutes for a 512 x  512 image using the one with n^3 complexity.

Is there any other algorithms to compute DCT having a minimal time complexity?

How does matlab do it so quickly though?

Comment: Matlab computes the DCT via the DFT, using the `fft` function. This function uses very effficient algorithms (usually O(_n_ log(_n_)). The algorithm selected depends on the input size. Internally, `fft` calls [`fftw`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftw.html), which defines [those algorithms](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftw.html#inputarg_method), and is based on the [FFTW library](http://www.fftw.org/)

Answer (score 3):

there are 2 common approaches for fast **DCT**.

1. **DCT from DFT**

   **1D DCT** can be derived from **1D DFT** in `O(n)` so when **FFT** algorithm is applied you got `O(n.log(n))` for **1D** and `O(n^2.log(n))` for **2D**. For more info see:

   - [I am looking for a simple algorithm for fast DCT and IDCT of matrix [NxM]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22779268/2521214)

   This approach is more used as it is a bit more easy to implement. There are more ways on how to derive **DCT** from **DFT** some use the same array size and the other uses double size for **DFT**.
2. **Fast DCT**

   There are also fast **DCT** equations out there but they are not commonly used because they are not very well known and not well documented online. Another more inmportant point is that the recursive breakdown involves both **DCT** and **DST** and the split is done usually into 3 therms instead of 2 which makes the implementation much harder. And also we need fast **DST** implementation which is analogy to **DCT** so it also breaks down to 3 therms and is using both **DCT** and **DST**. The bright side is that it does not involve complex domain but as you can imagine there is much more code needed in comparison to **#1**.

   From a quick search I found this

   - [The fast DCT-IV/DST-IV computation via the MDCT](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168403001099)

   But to find relevant info about fast **DCT** in real domain is a problem because most articles are either hard wired (constant `n`) implementations or are using approach **#1**. And when you find something it usually does contains errors and does not work. Your best bet for this approach is to find some **old** paper or book on computer graphics or discrete math.